# VBA Insert set number of rows if string found

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to macros in Excel, and I’m trying to speed up a process. I need to add a varying number of blank rows, if certain text is present in the cell above it. Not equal, but containing.

For example if A1 contains 'Apples', add two blank rows beneath. If A6 has 'Plums', add four blank rows beneath, etc.

What I have now is this:

```
    For a=1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(x1Up).Row
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(a,1).Value = “Apples” Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows(2).Insert
    a = a+1 

    ELSE
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(a,1).Value = “Plums” Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows(4).Insert
    a = a+1

    End If


    End Sub
```

So far I've gotten a Compile Error, stating "Block If without End If" though I believe I closed them both. I'm not sure if I'm correctly comparing or searching for a string as well (referring to my use of ="Apples"), but cannot get it to run at all to test that part.

Comment: I updated to show my code. I hadn’t included as I’m sure it’s wildly incorrect.

Comment: I voted to reopen based on your latest edit.

Comment: Still voting to leave closed. You haven't specified what's wrong with the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
For a = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If TypeName(ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 1)) = "String" Then
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 1).Value = "Apples" Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(2).Insert
            a = a + 1
            
        ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 1).Value = "Plums" Then 'One error here
            ActiveSheet.Rows(4).Insert
            a = a + 1
            
        End If
    End If
Next 'And here too
```

Comment: I receive at error at line two: "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch". Do I need to assign a variable to use here instead?

Comment: You need to check the type. Check the edited answer